# Unable to open files returned by readdir in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a problem with a Perl script, as follows.

I must open and analyze all the *.txt files in a directory, but I cannot.

I can read file names that are saved in the `@files` array and printed, but I cannot open those files for reading.

This is my code:

    `my $dir= "../Scrivania/programmi" ;`

```
opendir my ($dh), $dir;
my @files = grep { -f and /\.txt/i } readdir $dir;
closedir $dh;

for my $file ( @files ) {
$file = catfile($dir, $file);
print qq{Opening "$file"\n};
open my $fh, '<', $file;

# Do stuff with the data from $fh

print "sono nel foreach\n";
print " in : "."$fh\n";
#open(CANALI,$fh);
#@righe=<CANALI>;
#close(CANALI);
#print "canali:"."@righe\n";
#foreach $canali (@righe)
#{
#   $canali =~ /\d\d:\d\d (-) (.*)/;
#   $ora= $1;
#   
#   if($hhSplit[0] == $ora) 
#   {
#       push(@output, "$canali");
#       
#   }
#}

}
```

Comment: You actually using regex but you mentioned as glob

Comment: I've read that with perl there can be more than one way of doing it.  In this case you already have the file names in @files, maybe you just need to iterate through that array and use a regular expression to filter the file names you're looking for.  Then paste the file name and the directory name together and use the path to access the file.

Comment: how about `for my $fn ( grep{ $_ =~ /\.txt$/ }@files ){` ?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem you have is that the file names returned by `readdir` have no path, so you're trying to open, say, `x.txt` when you should be opening `../Sc/direct/x.txt`. The file doesn't exist in the current working directory so your `open` call fails

You also have a strange mixture of stuff in `glob("$dir/(.*).txt/")` which looks a little like a regex pattern, which `glob` doesn't understand. The value of `$dir` is a directory handle left open from the `opendir` on the first line. What you should be using is `glob '../Sc/direct/*.txt'`, but then there's no need for the `readdir`

There are two ways to find the contents of a file. You can use `opendir` and `readdir` to read everything in the directory, or you can use `glob`

The first method returns only the bare name of each entry, which means you must concatenate each name with the path to the containing directory, preferably using `catfile` from [File::Spec::Functions](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Spec::Functions). It also includes the pseudo-directories `.` and `..` so you must filter those out before you can use the list of names

`glob` has neither of these disadvantages. All the strings it returns are real directory entries, and they will include a path if you provided one in the pattern you passed as a parameter

You seem to have become rather muddled over the two, so I have written this program which differentiates between the two approaches. I hope it makes things clearer

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10.1;
use autodie;

use File::Spec::Functions qw/ catfile /;

my  $dir = '../Sc/direct';


### Using glob

for my $file ( glob catfile($dir, '*.txt') ) {
    print qq{Opening "$file"\n};
    open my $fh, '<', $file;

    # Do stuff with the data from $fh
}


### Using opendir / readdir

opendir my ($dh), $dir;
my @files = grep { -f and /\.txt$/i } readdir $dir;
closedir $dh;

for my $file ( @files ) {
    $file = catfile($dir, $file);
    print qq{Opening "$file"\n};
    open my $fh, '<', $file;

    # Do stuff with the data from $fh
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comments. i tried that but i have a problem with the continuation. what is wrong in the follow code?

Comment: pleas read up the code :/ in the first message

Comment: I need to locate in the directory 'programmi' all programs that fall under the time indicated. For example, if the time indicated is 21 must be returned all the programs provided in the entire time (thus, for example, those programmed for 21:00, 21:15, 21:30, 21:55, etc.) The 'programmi' directory contains several text files (for example, Rai 1, Rai 2, Rai 3, RaiMovie, Raisport1, etc), each of which defines the television program schedule for a day

Answer (score -1):

Using `$dir` in the glob is incorrect. `$dir` is a GLOB type not a string value. Rather you should be looping over the `@files` array and looking for names that match what you want. Maybe something like so:

```
foreach my $fp (@files) {
  if ($fp =~ /(.*).txt/) {
    print "$fp is a .txt\n";
    open (my $in, "<", $fp)
    while (<$in>) ...
  }
}
```

Comment: While it may be true that `$dir` is a *reference* to a glob, it's generally considered to be a  lexical directory handle and it's best to think of it that way

Comment: That code won't compile; the `open` call won't find the files because it's looking in the wrong directory, which is the problem the OP had originally; the regex doesn't need that capture `(.*)` in it, and it should really have a case-independent modifier `/i`